# Is "es macht mir Freude" correct and used?

Tags: expression

Is this expression equivalent to "it makes me happy"? Does it sound ok or maybe too old style? 
Would I ever hear a young person saying it? Is this expression used or common?

Comment: It is not only correct, it is very good german. And yet the expression is common enough not to be taken as elaborated. Use it, and everybody who loves his german mother's language will like you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two things:

"X macht mir Freude" corresponds more closely to "I like doing X". "X makes me happy" would be "X macht mich froh/glücklich".

And to express "I like...", "Spaß machen" is somewhat more usual than "Freude machen", although it's still perfectly understandable.

Comment: Not forgetting "gern", of course, to express enjoyment of an activity in a more general sense.

Answer (score 3):

*Es macht mir Freude* is grammatically correct, but sounds a little bit strange in everyday verbal communication.

I'd use *Es freut mich*.

Comment: Be careful! "Es freut mich, dass Sie schreiben, denn das Schreiben macht Ihnen Freude". The first means "I am glad " the second "it gives you enjoyment". The expressions are not interchangeable and "es macht mir Freude" is excellent German and reasonably common in everyday life!